# When should I use "了" in “把”字句 and where should it be placed?

Tags: grammar

A completed action with 把 sentence - I saw some sentences with 了 and some without 了. Is there a rule?

> 我把课本放在桌子上。
>
> 他把病人送到医院。

but

> 姐姐把照片存在电脑里了。
>
> 我把我的新书丢在公共汽车上了

and is there a difference where the 了 is placed?

> 小明把礼物送给了妈妈。

Comment: interestingly first 2 examples of 把-sentences have 在 with 了 occurring at the end, while in sentences that are not 把-sentences, the aspect particle (动态助词）了 comes right after 在 （to confirm general validity jukuu＂把在＂）。Also note that 3rd example has ("indirect") object 妈妈 besides direct object 礼物 which of course comes before verb right after 把，so that the usual rule of putting 了 between verb and object (妈妈）can be followed, otherwise aspect particle 了 at the end of sentence seems to be the usual situation.

Answer (score 4):

Compare these sentences:

> 1. 我把课本放在桌子上。
> 2. 他把病人送到医院。
> 3. 我把课本放在桌子上了。
> 4. 他把病人送到了医院。

Sentence 1 and 2 don't indicate the tense and tell whether those events happen in the present, past or future. Sentence 3 and 4 clearly indicate those events happened in the past because they have 了.

Practically, you could put 了 after verb. If you see a prepositional phrase in the end, you can attach 了 at the end of the prepositional phrase or sentence.

For example,

> 1. 我把课本放在桌子上了。 在桌子上 is a prep phrase, so you attach 了 at the end. The same thing for 姐姐把照片存在电脑里了。 我把我的新书丢在公共汽车上了.
> 2. 他把病人送到了医院。in this case, it doesn't have any prep phrase in the end, so you can put 了 after the verb 送到. In 小明把礼物送给了妈妈。送给 is the verb, so
>      you can put 了 after it.

Comment: ‘送到’的‘到’不是介词吗？bring to the hospital, give to his Mama?

Comment: @Pedroski, in 送到， 到 is used as a verb complement, indicating 目的 or 结果.

Comment: Yes, 送到 = sent to.

Answer (score 0):

"了" Equivalent to the past perfect tense,Means the end of things, the completion of actions

For example：

我把面包吃了!

If it is not added, it is a command, a request, a recommendation

For example：

你把电脑打开。

Answer (score 0):

1. 我把手機賣了。
2. 我要把手機賣了。
3. 我要把手機賣。

Sentence 1, the action completed.
Sentence 2, the action seems haven't been completed. (not happen yet)
Sentence 3, it's a wrong sentence.

In this case, why should we use 了 in 1 and 2? Is it any chance that sometimes we must use 了 because of the specific verb or there is other reason?
I would appreciate it if anyone can share your insight here.